# Custom Post and Pagination in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I know there is plenty of information out there on pagination and custom post types, but after doing the research and trying a few different methods, I'm just not having any luck.

Would greatly appreciate any thoughts of why the code below isn't working:

```
<!-- main content -->
<main class="main-content">

  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

  <div class="projects">

    <?php
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

      $args = array(
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'projects',
      'meta_key' => 'project-status',
      'meta_value' => 'Completed Project',
      'paged' => $paged,
      'showposts' => 3
      );

      $project = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php
      if ( $project->have_posts() ) :
      while ( $project->have_posts() ) : $project->the_post();
    ?>

        <?php get_template_part('content-project'); ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php
      wp_pagenavi();
      wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

</main>
```

Comment: What problem do you face?

Comment: The pagination isn't showing.

Comment: Well...`wp_pagenavi()` isn't a WordPress function. Are you using the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) for some reason?

Comment: I've used it before and liked it .. the plugin is installed. I've had a normal WordPress function in its place and it still wasn't showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use `numberposts` and `showposts` together in the same query

Secondly, `numberposts` is meant to be used with `get_posts`. In `WP_Query` it is an invalid parameter

Thirdly, showposts has been dropped in favor of `posts_per_page`

For the pagination and how to use wp_pagenavi, have a look at the documentation on the [author's website](http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/). According to the docs, this should work

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $project ) );
```